# Can I add type parameters to golang methods?

Tags: go, generics

```golang
type Vec[T any] []T

func NewVec[T any](cap int) Vec[T] {
    return make([]T, 0, cap)
}

func (v Vec[T]) Len() int {
    return len(v)
}


func (v Vec[T]) Map[U any](f func(T) U) Vec[U] {
    mapped := NewVec[U](v.Len())
    for _, elem := range v {
        mapped = append(mapped, f(elem))
    }
    return mapped
}
```

this is my code, compiler complain "method must have no type parameters" for the `Map` method, is there any way to bypass this error?

Comment: You can’t. Only on function, not methods. Perhaps on go 1.19

Comment: Perhaps on go 2 